# ASP.NET WebAPI 2 - MessageHandler return response before logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented some logging in WebAPI 2 via a MessageHandler.

It seems to me that the response is returned only AFTER the logging occurs.  It would be nice for the user to receive their response, but for the logging to be an after thought.  Is this possible?

```
public abstract class MessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected HttpRequestMessage requestMessage;
    protected HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var requestTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
        responseMessage = await base.SendAsync(requestMessage, token);
        var responseTime = DateTime.Now;

        await LogEntryAsync(requestTime, responseTime);
        return responseMessage;
    }

    protected abstract Task LogEntryAsync(DateTime requestTime, DateTime responseTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, it's possible. 
The usual way to handle this is to place the message in a concurrent queue consumed by a thread that deals with logging from all sources.
The thread and the queue would be encapsulated inside a Logger class with an interface similar to:

```
public class ILog
{
    void Debug(....);
    void Info(....);
    void Warning(....);
}
```

and your code would look like:

```
ILog Log {get; set;}

protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken token)
{
    var requestTime = DateTime.Now;
    this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
    responseMessage = await base.SendAsync(requestMessage, token);
    var responseTime = DateTime.Now;

    log.Info(requestTime, responseTime); // No async needed
    return responseMessage;
}
```

Blocking (for say database or file logs) would then occur on the consumer thread instead of the main thread that handles the user HTTP session.

The real question is why would you want to implement this yourself when several widely available libraries already do it for you and better than you would hope to achieve without spending a prohibitive amount of time on a comprehensive log solution (see NLog, Log4Net, CommonLogging).